# Does the GMT of the server time change on Daylight saving?

Tags: php, apache

I have this command:

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

which right now gives out a `-0400` as the GMT value.

I don't remember what was the value before March 8th (the change into daylight saving time). was it still `-0400`? or maybe it was `-0500`?

(I have a different script that is supposed to by synched with my server time so I need to know this to understand whether should I change the GMT of my script which is manually set to `-0400`)

Comment: No, GMT is a constant..... GMT never changes during the year.... time simply changes relative to GMT.... that `-04:00` or `-05:00` is the __local timezone difference__ (with/without daylight saving) relative to GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark said, GMT doesn't change. Only (possibly) your local offset.

To work out the GMT offset for a particular date, you can use [timezone_offset_get](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php) which will return the offset in seconds.

Example for Dominican Republic:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Dominica');
$date = new DateTime('2015-03-07', $timezone);
echo $timezone->getOffset($date);
```

Note that most countries in the GMT-4 time zone don't actually have any daylight saving changes, so you might find that the offset is always exactly the same, depending on the country.

Comment: Well, I just asked my webhost and they told me that in fact it does change. they told me that I would have got a `-0500` for this php command up until sunday.

Comment: They are wrong. GMT is constant. If GMT ever changed, the clocks all over the world would get messed up. Have a read through this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time - what might change is the offset for the timezone of your particular server. In which case, your server is not running on GMT.

Comment: Run `echo date_default_timezone_get();` and it will tel you what you are using

Comment: the output is `America/New_York`, what does it mean? I am talking about the `O` value - I don't know if it's called GMT, in the php manual it is described as `Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours`

Comment: what I meant is - does it indicate the my server is running on GMT, or is it running on the Offset you mentioned?

Comment: It means your server is running on *New York time*, which is currently 4 hours behind GMT. If you look at the chart on the link I posted, it will explain that before March 9th it was 5 hours behind GMT.

Comment: so back to my original question, for the given code - did the output was indeed `-0500` before March 8?

Comment: If you put in the correct timezone, then it will output the correct value. Try it.

Comment: I'm asking about a past event, so there's really nothing to try here

Comment: oops, didn't notice the code. for new york it yields out `-18000`, perhaps there's an error in it?

Comment: Read right above the code: "which will return the offset in **seconds**" so divide by 3600 (just edited, did say minutes!)

Comment: ok so for March 7 I got 5 hours. and for march 10 I got 4 hours, thanks!